# Lost money with Bitcoin Core wallet

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

I was sent $750 worth of BTC on 11/29/17. On 1/7/18, I finally got to 11/29/17 while syncing the blockchain to the core wallet and my coin arrived. However, on 1/7/18 I tried to send part of it to the Bread wallet and the rest to an online site. The Core wallet debited the coin and I was expecting that when it synced to 1/7/18 the money would arrive to those places. However, the blockchain has passed 1/7/18 and my coin has not reached the receivers.

These are the transactions that have not arrived:

```
https://blockchain.info/address/15x75nezMGZvF9KS4DxnSoJ33gdDy8C72a
https://blockchain.info/address/1FymHcBdWnoHtecA2qEkbwYpTzAJqDiNjc
```

Answer (score 1):

You linked adresses. Not transaction ID's.

It seems to me that you A. either failed to broadcast your transaction, or B. you broadcasted it with a fee that was so low that nodes eventually dropped your transaction.

( Or maybe your coins got double spend?)

A is much more likely. Are you sure you are spending the right outputs? I can't really give a solution other then that you should try to simply rebroadcast your transaction with the information i currently have.

Comment: I am not sure about A. How would I broadcast them? It shows as being sent in the wallet and they deducted the coin immediately. Also not sure about B. I just checked the box that said to deduct the fee which in the Core wallet said was estimated to be .00002 or something.

Comment: Could you give me the transaction ID or raw transaction hex? I think somehow your bitcoin core is blocking you from broadcasting the tx. ( Check if you're connected to a node.

Comment: Also, the Bread wallet showed how much the transaction is worth even though I never gave it the amount, only the address. The coin even appeared in my wallet for a few minutes before it vanished. So they obviously recognized this at least temporarily.

Comment: f095e4d01ee07e03c3a075f33da5ce3bb88958e343c5a3fa283b6f92411f8e60

Comment: that is the ID for one of the transactions. if you can provide directions on how to make sure it broadcasted please let me know. I'll happily send you $50 worth of bitcoin if you can solve this for me.

Comment: Open up the RPC console and then you try `abandontransaction f095e4d01ee07e03c3a075f33da5ce3bb88958e343c5a3fa283b6f92411f‌​8e60`, then resend/rebroadcast it? If that doesn't do it Then use `-zapwallettxes`

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you explain? I am on a Mac.

Comment: Click Help -> Debug -> Console

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is this code I am supposed to enter? Not sure exactly where to put it.

Comment: Go to the mac terminal, close your bitcoin core, and run, `bitcoin-qt -zapwallettxes`, then restart your bitcoin core.

Comment: i had to leave so I can't restart the wallet until i get home later tonight. but when i put this code into the Terminal it says command can not be found

Comment: You'll need to go into the /Applications/ where you located bitcoin core

Comment: I don't see where to enter that code in the Applictions

Comment: I found all the blockchain transactions in that Applications file.